# node.js , how to make centralized transaction

Tags: node.js

were making a human resource system using node.js, we centralized it (using different laptops but accessing same folder), while laptop A is viewing his profile, while laptop B is viewing his information, the problem is when laptop A  refresh his page, the result will be the page of Laptop B(same as laptop B , if he refresh his page the result will be the page of Laptop A)..in short if that page is refresh , the result will be the page of the other laptop same as the other one.
does it something wrong with our code:? since we accesing same port?

```
            MongoClient.connect(url, (err, database) => {
              // ... start the server
              if (err) return console.log(err)
              db = database
              app.listen(3000, () => {
                console.log('listening on 3000')
              })
            })
```

any ideas? pls help...to resolve this.